# Why does an anti-unitary operator have to be both left and right anti-unitary?

Tags: quantum-information

I am reading about anti-unitary operators from here [anti-linear operators](http://info.phys.unm.edu/~caves/reports/antilinearops.pdf). They have defined an anti-unitary operator $$K: |\psi\rangle \to K|\psi\rangle$$  $$K(\alpha|\psi\rangle+\beta|\phi\rangle) =\alpha^*K(|\psi\rangle)+\beta^*K(|\phi\rangle)$$

But then they impose the condition $$ \langle\phi|(K|\psi\rangle) = [(\langle\phi|K)|\psi\rangle]^{*}$$

That is $K$ maps the dual of vectors also in an anti-unitary manner ( ie. is both left and right anti-unitary, if I am not wrong ). Is there a reason for imposing the last condition or am I missing something trivial ? Also the result differs by a complex conjugate if we take it as a left or a right anti-unitary. Is there a physical significance for it , because I only read previously about linear operators where left or right does not make difference , but here it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In proper mathematical terms, the action on the left is actually an action on the dual of the Hilbert space. The most natural way of defining this map is just by a simple transposition of the operator. For instance one could define the left action of $K$ to be
$$K(\phi,\ \cdot\ ) := (K^*\phi,\ \cdot\ ).$$
If one views this as a map on the Hilbert space to its dual, then this is linear because
$$K(\lambda\phi,\ \cdot\ ) = (K^*\lambda\phi,\ \cdot\ ) = (\bar\lambda K^*\phi,\ \cdot\ ) = \lambda(K^*\phi,\ \cdot\ )=\lambda K(\phi,\ \cdot\ ).$$
Hence if you want to define an antilinear left action on the Hilbert space one has to take a complex conjugation, as done in the OP. The reason for such a choice are motivated in the link provided by the OP. Observe that the above map is indeed antilinear on the dual to itself, so the definition proposed in the OP is actually a linearization of this correspondence, i.e. a map from the dual to the complex conjugate of the dual (or viceversa).